# Execute block of code before every message

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I'm currently tagging all my logs with trace details, whenever an actor or Future is encountered there is chance that a new thread would execute the next set of lines as a result I need update the span details.

Basically, I need to run few lines of code for every case in receive method.

```
class MyActor() extends Actor{
    override def receive: Receive = {
       case Foo() => {
           //update span details
           some logic for Foo
       }
       case Bar() => {
              //update span details
              some logic for BAR
       }
       case a: SomeType =>  
           //update span details
           some logic for SomeType message
    }
}
```

Is there any way to execute the `update span details` lines for every message by default something like `@beforeEach`

Answer (score 1):

Since `Receive` is just `PartialFunction[Any, Unit]`:

```scala
def updateSpanDetails(pf: PartialFunction[Any, Unit]): PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = {
  case msg if pf.isDefinedAt(msg) =>
    // update span details
    pf(msg)
}
```

```scala
class MyActor() extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = updateSpanDetails {
    case Foo() =>
      ???

    case Bar() =>
      ???

    case a: SomeType =>
      ???
  }
}
```

Disclaimer: only mentally compiled